# Postgresql save query result in 2d array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, 2d

I would like to create 2d array inside a function and populate it with values from select statement. I try this code and end up with one-dimension array. What am I doing wrong?

```
select array(select a from t a)
=====================================
"{"(1,stxt,varchar)","(2,sint,int)"}"


create or replace function __test(
) returns text
language 'plpgsql' as
$$
declare
  _dat varchar[][];

begin

  _dat = (select array(select a from t a));

  return array_dims(_dat);

end;
$$;


select __test();
===========
"[1:2]"
```

I expected last command to return [1:2][1:3]  for two rows of three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL support only one type arrays - so you can take only array of row / you can't to take 2D array what you would. There are no way how to do it well now.